# 2006 Honda Civic EX turned off wouldn't start, all lights work and windows but only clicks when ignition is turned over

Tags: battery, ignition-key, no-crank-no-start

Put new alternator on an the key has a chip but, the key was taped kind of when I got it. I just recently got the car an the person I got it from said it been sitting a little while. Dad she an her daughter stopped at a rest area an used the restroom. When that came back out an went to start car it would not start. She had it towed to her house an it has set since.

Comment: Have the battery and charging system tested, you may have a very low battery.

Comment: I Have done this already

Answer (score 1):

Is it just one "tick" or is it a lot of "ticks" with the dash lights flickering and the needles going up and down real fast?

just one "tick" - It could either be a dead battery or the starter solenoid. Get a jump start to rule out the battery, but if it still doesn't start, I'd personally replace the starter.

bunch of "ticks" and dash going crazy - I'm pretty positive it's the battery. Get a jump start to verify.

You can use a multi-meter to test the battery as well. Here's a pretty good guide on how. [How to Diagnose a Bad Car Battery](https://practicalmechanic.com/2019/03/17/how-to-diagnose-a-bad-car-battery/#:%7E:text=Clean%20the%20Battery%20Connections%20%20%20Year%20,%20%2014.39%20%201%20more%20rows%20)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

My moms car does the same thing and she has to put shift the gear to neutral than the car turns on. I don’t know why